# Qt5 VideoPlayer: Does not play .mp4 file

Tags: qt, video, qt5, video-player

My problem is little bit strange for me. I wrote a mediaPlayer program.
And I move the executable file to another directory in the same machine. Put the dlls beside the exe. It works fine. It can plays .mp4,.avi etc. But when i move the exe and dlls another machine it doesn't play mp4 files. 
I tried compile both MinGW and VS2012 and result is same. Didn't find why. 
Is there a advice for me ?

Thanks.

Comment: this is probably not related to qt, just codecs are installed on one machine and are not installed on the other

Answer (score 1):

Install a default codec pack onto the end user's machine or convert the mp4 to a codec sponsored by windows.

### Codec Pack Recommendation

It is hard to go wrong with **K-lite Basic Codec Pack**.  Just be careful when downloading because the main download site is riddled with ads and false download buttons.

My preferred way to install something like this on my development machine is to use chocolatey.  First install chocolatey then in your admin cmd, run:

```
choco install k-litecodecpackbasic
```

### Video Conversion Tool Recommendation

Handbrake.  Occasionally `ffmpeg` or `libav` might be better suited, but for most cases go with Handbrake.

### If You Can't Install New Codecs...

On the end user's machine (missing admin privileges) or something else, then you probably need to use vlc's library for video playback if you need to support more than the minimum supported out of the box by Windows.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But the package was not found with the sources list.

Comment: Which package in which sources list?